# Mysql restrict value of a field to be one of the defined ones

Tags: mysql, validation

I am using mysql database.

I have a field `user_type` in `USER` table. I would like to restrict the values in this field to be one of ('ADMIN','AGENT','CUSTOMER').

The insert statements should fail if they tried to insert anything else than the above possible values. Also, I need defaulting to 'CUSTOMER' is none is specified in the insert statements.

The possible solution I could think of is use of `triggers`, but I would like to know How this could be handled more efficiently (possibly in the create table ddl itself?).

Any ideas, How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what the [column type "enum"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) is for. You treat it like a string, and behind the scenes it is stored as an int, and must be one of the values defined in the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  user_type enum('ADMIN', 'AGENT', 'CUSTOMER') NOT NULL default 'CUSTOMER'
)
```

Then insert like so:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_type) VALUES ('ADMIN'); // success
INSERT INTO users (user_type) VALUES ('ANONYMOUS'); // failure (or '' if not "strict" mode)
INSERT INTO users (user_type) VALUES (default(user_type)); // uses default
INSERT INTO users () VALUES (); // uses default
INSERT INTO users (user_type) VALUES (NULL); // failure
```

## note

Note that for the query to actually fail, you must use "SQL strict mode". Otherwise, an "empty string" value (which is slightly special in that it has the numeric value of 0) is inserted.

Quoting [this docs page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html):

> When this manual refers to “strict mode,” it means a mode where at least one of STRICT_TRANS_TABLES or STRICT_ALL_TABLES is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. Any comment on how to default the insert statment with empty `user_type` it to 'CUSTOMER'?

Comment: Yeah, just either don't include it in the list of columns, or use the `default` function: `VALUES (default(user_type))`

Comment: I used to use ENUM all the time. However, it's less portable than other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post, and as it dates somewhat back, I was thinking of others coming across it these days too and miss the (in my opinion) simpler approach of simply adding a `CHECK`constraint (e.g. [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) for MySQL, or [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/) for MariaDB).

In my opinion, using a `CHECK` constraint is much easier than using things like `ENUM` and / or `SET` as you don't need to worry about the relations to integer indexes etc. when relying on them. They for example can become weird when you try to preset allowed integer values for a column.

Example, where you want to have a column which has values ranging from 1 to 5:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  myCol INT NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT CHECK (1 <= `myCol` <= 5)
);
```

Comment: JUST FYI: check constraint is supported in MySQL 8.0.16 and above only. Lower versions will parse the check clause and will generate no errors but it does nothing.

Comment: Jupjup I know! But yeh good for others that u added this info!